# Android 4.0.3 does not have application log output in logcat window

Tags: android, logging

I am using an Android 4.0.3 device and eclipse 4.2 with the most current ADT plugin and Android SDK.

I have tested the Android device with a "MyHelloWorld" project. The project runs OK. I have also added some "Log.i", "Log.v" statements in the MainActivity's onCreate method. However, I find that these Log statements do not generate any output in the eclipse logcat window. The eclipse logcat window does have some outputs related to the "MyHelloWorld" project (e.g. messages from the "Dalvik" java engine), but the messages from the "Log.i", "Log.v" statements do not exist.

My Android 4.0.3 device is a non-rooted device and I cannot read directly from "/dev/log/main" to check whether the "Log.i", "Log.v" statements have written anything into the Android Log.

I want to know that have I missed some settings in my Android phone and/or my eclipse setup ? What could I do to check whether the "Log.i", "Log.v" statements have written anything ? If I just want to have some debug outputs (output variable values) from my Android program, could I use other methods that do the same job as "Log.i", "Log.v" ?

Thanks for any suggestion.

(The problem is the same for eclipse 3.7.2 too)

Comment: Change your filer level in eclipse, or run 'adb logcat' from a command window on your development machine.

Comment: I have used "adb shell logcat > ~/logcat.txt" to capture all the log messages and then use a text editor to check for the "Log.i", "Log.v" messages from my program. But I find no such messages.

Comment: My phone upgraded from 4.0.4 to 4.1 and logging became flaky until i updated IDE. I think it has something to do with eclipse. Ddmd should work

Comment: I have also used "adb shell cat /dev/log/main", "adb shell cat /dev/log/events" and "adb shell cat /dev/log/system" to check for any messages from the "Log.i", "Log.v" statements from the "MyHelloWorld" project, but I find no such messages too. I am wondering whether the "Log.i", "Log.v" statements have written anything into the Android Log.

Comment: I face the same problem with my 4.0.3. But it seems to be an eclipse bug because at random times it comes.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe noobish or i got your question wrong but you could just use:

```
 System.out.println("You can print things in console with this.");
 int myVariable = 1101;
 System.out.println("You can print variable values:" + myVariable);
```

this way you can get output in you LogCat without using Log.v